# Dependency Injection Pattern seems extreme in Control Class

Tags: php

My Control Class basically picks which object / class to instantiate.  Because this is basically what it does it naturally has many objects / classes it calls.

If I use dependency injection I will be injecting all of these objects.  This seems bad for two reasons.

1. I've heard that about 3 dependent objects / classes is normal to KISS ( Keep it Simple Smarty)
2. Only one of the objects / classes will be used.  So in a sense the others are instantiated for no reason.

How do I resolve these design considerations to satisfy - decoupled code, but simple and used code?

Comment: You don't have to delete it. You just need to write it up as a separate question and answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking. Also, I removed the mentions of JavaScript since I saw nothing at all to do with JS here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is that you actually map some parameter onto some functionality, a so called *script* or *action*.

So in the end you only need a convention how to map that parameter or name onto some function. As functions can be somewhere (in some other object, in the global space, anonymous), you don't really need to inject many objects into your control class, but functions and the mapping.

If you would than even add some more differentiation with function name and parameters (or "modules" and "actions"), well then, you could drastically reduce your code and you can actually make the request inject the dependency:

**Script or Action**

```
 Mapping:                  Actions:                  

 "*"                       "_.Exception.Invalid ajax_type"                        
 "signin_control"          "A.SignIn.invoke"
 "signup_control"          "A.SignUp.invoke"  
 "tweet_control"           "A.Tweet.add"      
 "ControlBookmark_add"     "A.Bookmark.add"   
 "ControlBookmark_delete"  "A.Bookmark.delete"
 "ControlTryIt"            "B.ControlTryIt"   
 "ControlSignOut"          "C.SignOut"

 Implementation:

 $action = $map[isset($map[$ajax_type]) ? $ajax_type : '*'];

 Session::start();

 call_user_func_array(
     'call_user_func_array',
     explode('.', $action) + array(NULL, NULL, NULL)
 );

 function _($a, $b) {
     throw new $a($b);
 }

 function A($a, $b) {         
     $maker = new ObjectMaker();
     $maker->$a()->$b();
 }

 function B($a) {
     new $a();
 }

 function C($a) {
    Session::finish();
    B($a);
 }
```

This pseudo-code shows the actual business of your control class: Call some functions based on it's input. The concrete dependencies are:

- `ObjectMaker`
- `Session`
- `$map`

As session is static, you should replace it with something that actually can be injected.

As `$map` is an array, it can be injected, but the logic of the mapping might need to become something more internal, so if `$map` is an `ArrayAccess`, this can happen already.

The non-concrete dependencies are hidden inside the actual `$ajax_type`, so these dependencies are dependent on that parameter through mapping, which is already a dependency. So the last dependency is:

- `$ajax_type`

This dependency is related to both the control class and the mapping. So the control class itself could be made a dependency to the ajax type as well. But as you use a static global function, I'll simplify this inside a class function so actually dependencies can be passed into it. I put the factory into a global function and the ajax types are loaded from an ini-file:

```
function ajax_control_factory($inifile)
{
    $maker   = new ObjectMaker();
    $session = new SessionWrap();
    $types   = new AjaxTypesIni($inifile);
    return new AjaxControl($maker, $session, $types);
}

$control = ajax_control_factory($inifile);

printf("Call an nonexistent ajax type: ");
try {
    $control->invokeByType('blurb');
    printf(" - I so failed!\n");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf("Exception caught! All good!\n");
}

printf("Add me a bookmark: ");
$control->invokeByType("ControlBookmark_add");
printf("Done! Fine! Superb this works!\n");
printf("Do the two control functions: ");

$control->invokeByType("ControlTryIt");
$control->invokeByType("ControlSignOut");
printf("Done! Fine! Superb this works!\n");
```

Ini file:

```
*                       = _.Exception.Invalid ajax_type
signin_control          = A.SignIn.invoke
signup_control          = A.SignUp.invoke
tweet_control           = A.Tweet.add
ControlBookmark_add     = A.Bookmark.add
ControlBookmark_delete  = A.Bookmark.delete
ControlTryIt            = B.ControlTryIt
ControlSignOut          = C.SignOut
```

To have this work, this needs some stubs for mocking, which is easy with your example:

```
class Mock
{
    public $stub;

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        return class_exists($this->stub) ? new $this->stub() : $this->stub;
    }
}

class ObjectMaker extends Mock
{
    public $stub = 'Mock';
}

class ControlTryIt {}
class SignOut {}

class SessionWrap
{
    public function start()
    {
        // session::start();
    }

    public function stop()
    {
        // session::finish();
    }
}
```

Those are enough to run the code above which will  give:

```
Call an nonexistent ajax type: Exception caught! All good!
Add me a bookmark: Done! Fine! Superb this works!
Do the two control functions: Done! Fine! Superb this works!
```

The ajax types:

```
class AjaxTypes extends ArrayObject
{
    private $default;
    private $types;

    public function __construct(array $types, $default)
    {
        parent::__construct($types);
        $this->default = $default;
    }

    public function offsetGet($index)
    {
        return parent::offsetExists($index) ? parent::offsetGet($index) : $this->default;
    }
}

class AjaxTypesIni extends AjaxTypes
{
    public function __construct($inifile)
    {
        $map = parse_ini_file($inifile);
        if (!isset($map['*'])) throw new UnexpectedValueException('No * entry found.');
        $default = $map['*'];
        unset($map['*']);
        parent::__construct($map, $default);
    }
}
```

And the ajax controler:

```
class AjaxControl
{
    private $types;
    private $maker;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(ObjectMaker $maker, SessionWrap $session, AjaxTypes $types)
    {
        $this->types   = $types;
        $this->maker   = $maker;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function invokeByType($type)
    {
        $session = $this->session;
        $maker   = $this->maker;
        $invoke = function($action) use ($session, $maker)
        {
            $_ = function($a, $b)
            {
                throw new $a($b);
            };
            $A = function($a, $b) use ($maker)
            {
                $maker->$a()->$b();
            };

            $B = function ($a)
            {
                new $a();
            };

            $C = function ($a) use ($B, $session)
            {
                $session->stop();
                $B($a);
            };

            $args = explode('.', $action) + array(NULL, NULL, NULL);
            $func = array_shift($args);
            call_user_func_array(${$func}, $args);
        };
        $invoke($this->types[$type]);
        $this->session->start();
    }
}
```

This is just exemplary. There is no guarantee that this fits as a design for your needs, just for demonstrating purposes. What it shows is that your actual controller function is not normalized / modular enough. When you better analyze the dependencies that exist and you inject them instead that you hardencode them, you will automatically find the best way to design *your* system.

What this example shows as well is that you have a tons of hidden dependencies for the request and response. You really need to draw lines somewhere and define what you pass through and in which direction. Say goodbye to global static state. Always inject. You can even start with function that need everything as parameters if it helps.

Comment: But My Request does inject the dependency.....through the code to ObjectMaker...see below....

Comment: Where do you access the file?

Comment: The ini file? I have that as string: `$inifile = 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode('
*                       = _.Exception.Invalid ajax_type
signin_control          = A.SignIn.invoke
signup_control          = A.SignUp.invoke
tweet_control           = A.Tweet.add
ControlBookmark_add     = A.Bookmark.add
ControlBookmark_delete  = A.Bookmark.delete
ControlTryIt            = B.ControlTryIt
ControlSignOut          = C.SignOut');` (multiline originally, for testing).

Comment: you said  - "ini-file:" that's why  I asked.  why do you have call_user_func....call_user_func_array...are your trying to confuse me?  Can you explain this answer...it is vitally important to how I structure my code...I think there is good info...but I can't read this man...it's hard to read...I'm a novice to intermediate level..not expert, which I'm guessing you are.

Comment: @TheAllFoo: The first code-block is *pseudo code* for specification. On the left side you see your strings and on the right sight you see a classifaction what they stand for (the action). Both together is a mapping of the ajax string to the action. Below that block you find the pseudocode that resolves the action string to actual functions. But all is pseudo and a simplification. It's the description of how the real code example works (which is larger and therefore not that fast to grasp, hence the pseudo code).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

By placing the dependency injection in the factory pattern ( Object Maker ), I can pull out all of the dependencies into one dependency - Object Maker - note below.

**PHP Control**

```
class Control
{
    public static function ajax($ajax_type)
    {
        Session::start();
        switch($ajax_type) 
        {
            case 'signin_control': // uses Message, Text, Database
                $Object = new ObjectMaker();
                $ObjectSignIn=$Object->makeSignIn();
                $ObjectSignIn->invoke();
                break; 
            case 'signup_control':// uses Message, Text, Database
                $Object = new ObjectMaker();
                $ObjectSignUp=$Object->makeSignUp();
                $ObjectSignUp->invoke(); 
                break;
            case 'tweet_control':// uses Message, Text, Database
                $Object = new ObjectMaker();
                $ObjectTweet=$Object->makeTweet();
                $ObjectTweet->add(); 
                break; 
            case 'ControlBookmark_add': // uses Message, Text, Database
                $Object = new ObjectMaker();
                $ObjectBookmark = $Object->makeBookmark();
                $ObjectBookmark->add();
                break; 
            case 'ControlBookmark_delete':// uses Database
                $Object = new ObjectMaker();
                $ObjectBookmark=$Object->makeBookmark();
                $ObjectBookmark->delete(); 
                break; 
            case 'ControlTryIt': // Why Not Session
                new ControlTryIt();
                break; 
            case 'ControlSignOut': 
                Session::finish();
                new ControlSignOut();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid ajax_type');
        }
    }
```

**ObjecMaker**

```
class ObjectMaker
{
    public function makeSignUp()
    {
        $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        $TextObject = new Text();
        $MessageObject = new Message();

        $SignUpObject = new ControlSignUp();        
        $SignUpObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $SignUpObject;
    }
    public function makeSignIn()
    {
        $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        $TextObject = new Text();
        $MessageObject = new Message();

        $SignInObject = new ControlSignIn();
        $SignInObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $SignInObject;
    }
    public function makeTweet( $DatabaseObject = NULL, $TextObject = NULL, $MessageObject = NULL )
    {
        if( $DatabaseObject == 'small' )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        }
        else if( $DatabaseObject == NULL )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
            $TextObject = new Text();
            $MessageObject = new Message();
        }
        $TweetObject = new ControlTweet();        
        $TweetObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $TweetObject;
    }
    public function makeBookmark( $DatabaseObject = NULL, $TextObject = NULL, $MessageObject = NULL )
    {
        if( $DatabaseObject == 'small' )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        }
        else if( $DatabaseObject == NULL )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
            $TextObject = new Text();
            $MessageObject = new Message();
        }
        $BookmarkObject = new ControlBookmark();        
        $BookmarkObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject,$TextObject,$MessageObject);
        return $BookmarkObject;
    }
}
```